# React download excel file preserving styling

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, excel, xlsx

I'm attempting to send an Excel file up from the server to the client as a downloadable file. I was initially doing this with the `xlsx` library on NPM, but the styling wasn't being preserved in the transfer. I did some research and found the `ExcelJS` library, but I'm not seeing a clear way how to send a file from the server to the client using `ExcelJS` that is presented as a downloadable file. Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need any libraries whatsoever to simply serve a file. a browser cant open an excel file so no matter how you serve it it will be downloaded. what is your server?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. It's a NodeJS server.

Comment: what does that mean? express? home rolled? what?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Sorry, brain is on the fritz this morning. Express.